# HTML style individual hover color

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="test.html" style="{color: blue; background: white} :visited {color: red} :hover {background: red} :visited:hover {color: red}">
            Test
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why it's not possible to set a `hover` attribute on this kind?

Comment: Give the link a class and set it there, :hover, :visited and such can't be applied inline

Answer (score 7):

Look at code below  and see if its what you mean, if so then try that.

```css
.css
{
    color: blue;
    background: white;
} 
.css:visited 
{
    color: red;
} 
.css:hover 
{
    background: red;
} 
.css:visited:hover 
{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="test.html" class="css">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `:hover` is part of the *selector* and when you use a `style` attribute you don't have a selector. The value of the `style` attribute is, effectively, the body of a *ruleset* (the ruleset applies to the element that has the `style` attribute instead of having a selector to describe where it applies).

Use a stylesheet if you want to use selectors. Don't use inline style attributes.